# How to upload file on google drive from my website?

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to use the Google drive API to upload files using my web app with an upload button. The back-end of the app is built with **Laravel API** and **mongodb**, and the front-end with **angularJs**. My end goal is for the file the user is uploading to be stored to a company's Google drive folder, not the user's (like Google file picker etc.) I'm a beginner when it comes to API, so any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a service account and Google OAuth 2.0 to upload files to a company account.

reference link : https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount

A service Account does have limitations.

For an alternative approach refer to this link : [How do I authorise an app (web or installed) without user intervention?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-a-background-web-app-without-user-intervention-canonical)