# Am I able to use dropbox or google drive as a storage in my website?

Tags: html, google-drive-api, dropbox

I'm just having a site and I don't want to store the user uploaded Files in my server . I want to store it in a cloud server or storage like gdrive or dropbox. Is  this possible todo?

Comment: Sure.  Have you tried?

Comment: I really don't know to use it through . How can I do that?

Comment: I think this will be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27247547/.

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  Please do some research into your question give it a try and come back if you have any issues with **your** solution.

Comment: If you read how to ask you might have better luck.  I would love to help you but your question is just to broad it would take to long to find out what you need i cant code this all for you its a huge project start by reading the documentation https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk  then give it a try yourself comeback if you have issues with **your** solution.  SO isnt a coding service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the Google Drive API for achieving this. Google Drive API is using OAuth 2.0 Authentication. You can find API Endpoints and Authentication methods from below link.

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads